# Weird glitch when in recovery menu

Tags: bug-reporting

In Ubuntu Desktop 20.04 when I do the steps to access recovery menu everything is normal and it displays recovery menu correctly for 5 seconds and then this happens:

[Image of the weird gui bug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K3D1w.jpg)

Comment: Did you modify /etc/default/grub? Is this a desktop or laptop? It kind of looks like maybe a keyboard problem is auto-selecting things in the GRUB menus. Laptop keyboard, or PC/USB keyboard?

Comment: laptop, you may be right there. Sorry for not responding but it didn't really end up being a problem, just a weird bug